# What does a comma mean in the output from running tests with phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have output from running a test suite with `phpunit`. I understand that periods (`.`) mean a passed test, but what does a comma (`,`) mean?

```
16:10:12
PHPUnit 6.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
..............................F...,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,....,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,E..,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...........,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
..........  63 / 145 ( 43%)
```

Comment: `,` isn't normally an output from phpunit. Are you `echo`ing the comma anywhere in your code?

Comment: User's own code was unintentionally generating commas, VTC as typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the string

```
..............................F...,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,....,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,E..,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...........,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
..........
```

and remove new lines, it amounts to **300** characters.

If we remove the `,`, it amounts to **63** characters, which matches the progress output from `phpunit`:

```
63 / 145
```

That is, as @Hollings suggested, you are echoing a `,` repeatedly in your tests somewhere.

You can adjust your `phpunit.xml` to be as strict as possible about risky tests:

```
<phpunit
    beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
    verbose="true"    
 >
    <testsuites>
        ...
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Specifically, you are looking to enable this option

```
beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
```

in combination with enabled verbosity

```
verbose="true"
```

If you then run the tests, `phpunit` will let you know which tests cause output, for example:

```
PHPUnit 6.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:    PHP 7.1.5
Configuration:  /Users/am/Sites/stackoverflow/45547842/phpunit.xml

R,

Time: 43 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 risky test:

1) FooTest::testBar
This test printed output: ,
```

For reference, see:

- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/risky-tests.html

Comment: If you like my answer, can you accept it? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I went through the code using this method and ending up finding a function that was sending files to Amazon SQS.  As it was waiting for the files to upload, it would output a comma (,).  This was the source of the commas!  With all the periods, E, F, S, I associated with PHPUnit, I naturally assumed that commas were part of that package.  Thanks to @localheinz for his thorough explanation.